# An error occurred after packaging when I used NuxT3-RC8 and Elements-Plus

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I got this error previewing after build

[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] The requested module '@popperjs/core' does not provide an export named 'default'

New error in build preview after update to RC10

[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] The requested module 'vue' does not provide an export named 'default'

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
import { ElementPlusResolver } from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers'

const lifecycle = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    '@vueuse/nuxt',
    '@unocss/nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/color-mode',
  ],
  experimental: {
    reactivityTransform: true,
    viteNode: true,
  },
  unocss: {
    preflight: true,
  },
  colorMode: {
    classSuffix: '',
  },
  hooks: {
    'vite:extendConfig': function (config: any, { isServer }: any) {
      if (isServer) {
        config.build.rollupOptions.output.inlineDynamicImports = true
      }
    },
  },
  vite: {
    plugins: [
      AutoImport({
        resolvers: [ElementPlusResolver()],
      }),
      Components({
        dts: true,
        resolvers: [ElementPlusResolver({ ssr: true })],
      }),
    ],
  },
  build: {
    transpile: [
      lifecycle === 'build' || lifecycle === 'generate' ? 'element-plus' : '',
      'element-plus/es',
    ],
  },
})
```

Comment: Hi, do you mind trying with the latest (RC10)? Also, do you mind giving more context regarding your configuration?

Comment: Thank you for your idea, but it has a new error now

Comment: Which one? Could you please provide more details?

Comment: Yes, please have a look

Comment: Do you have `vue` installed on your `package.json` or a package depending on an older version?

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea. I slowly went through each file and found the problem. Thank you very much

Comment: What was the actual issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.